# 20.04 Focal Fossa libpam0g:i386

Tags: 20.04

I have installed the server image of 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa).

My 64-bit database product from IBM requires a 32-bit library for compatibility reasons , but this 32-bit library is not found when I apt-get install libpam0g:i386.

(This 32-bit compatibility library was available on 18.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS).

The package name is 'libpam0g:i386'.
This is what I see:

```
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [89.1 kB]
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [97.9 kB]
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [368 B]
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [344 B]
Fetched 188 kB in 1s (248 kB/s)         
Reading package lists... Done

# apt-get install libpam0g:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpam0g:i386
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATES**

```
grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list" 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

Comment: Please add output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for ubuntu 20.04 the `libpam0g:i386` is renamed to **libpam_systemd:i386**

The following command worked for me, and delivered the 32-bit library that I needed:

`dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`sudo apt install libpam-systemd:i386`

==============

At first I tried manual installation of **libpam0g:i386** , and it also worked but with more steps for manual dependency handling. Not recommended.

copy `libpam0g_1.3.1-5ubuntu4_i386.deb`
from https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/i386/libpam0g-dev/download
to the target server.

The target server has no X server  (is headless), so in an ssh session:

```
apt update

dpkg --add-architecture i386

apt install libaudit1:i386

apt install libc6:i386

dpkg --install libpam0g_1.3.1-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
```

This installed the dependencies first, then the required libpam0g:i386, and the IBM software accepted this.  Much easier to use `apt install libpam-systemd:i386` because that delivered the dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Really it [is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=i386&searchon=names&keywords=libpam0g). You need to run `sudo apt-get update` first.

And then run `sudo apt-get install libpam0g:i386`

Comment: See updated question, this gives the same result "Unable to locate package libpam0g:i386"  . What am I missing?

Comment: I would recommend to change the mirror to `archive.ubuntu.com` . The package is in *main*, so it is difficult to not have it.